# Spring data Mongodb handling dates with @Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

Could you please help me on how to use @Query in Spring Data Mongodb to find data using Date ?

I have provided my code below:

**Repository Class:**

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {
    @Query("{ 'createdDateTime' : { $gt: ?0 } }")
    List<Customer> findAllCustomersByCreatedDate(Date date);
}
```

**ServiceImpl Class:**

```
@Service("CustomerService")
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    public List<Customer> findAllCustomersByCreatedDate(String createdDate) throws ParseException {
        return customerRepository.findAllCustomersByCreatedDate(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD").parse(createdDate));
    }
}
```

**RestController Class:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("customers")
public CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/byCreatedDate", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
    public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> findAllCustomersByCreatedDate(@RequestParam String createdDate)
            throws BusinessException, ParseException {

        List<Customer> customers = customerService.findAllCustomersByCreatedDate(createdDate);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(customers);
    }
}
```

**Data inside Mongo database for customers collection:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57851d1ee59782560e77ac3f"), 
  "_class" : "com.myproject.models.Customer", 
  "name" : "Rob",
  "createdBy" : "John", 
  "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-07-12T16:38:54.439Z")
}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5786222b29b42251b16b5233"), 
  "_class" : "com.myproject.models.Customer", 
  "name" : "Sara",
  "createdBy" : "John", 
  "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-07-13T08:38:52.116Z")
}
```

If I invoke the below URL with date string as "2016-07-19T14:38:54.439Z", it still returns 2 results (above 2 documents) even though there are no records created after 2016-07-19 in database.

http://localhost:8080/projects/byCreatedDate?createdDate=2016-07-19T14:38:54.439Z

What is the problem with my code above ? Could you please help ?

How Can I correct my code above to handle dates with Mongodb ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have spotted the problem which is the incorrect date format and changed the ServiceImpl class code as below, now the documents are fetched as expected:

```
return customerRepository.findAllCustomersByCreatedDate(
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse(createdDate)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way -

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate localDate = dtf.parseLocalDate(createdDate);    
Date dt = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
return customerRepository.findAllCustomersByCreatedDate(dt);
```